# RewriteRule Incorrectly Appending index.php

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^blog-details/(\d+)*$
```

To take me to this

```
./blog-details.php?post_id=$1
```

But I dont know why it's appending `index.php` like this:

```
blog-details.php/index.php
```

Instead of

```
blog-details.php/21
```

Comment: Please post your complete directives, not pseudo-code. And include the contents of your `.htaccess` file. By itself, a directive like that won't create that response. But your result doesn't make sense either. Why should it result in `blog-details.php/21` when you are supposedly rewriting to `./blog-details.php?post_id=$1`? (Also, `./` should not be used here.)

Comment: @MrWhite you get the point please can you help out with the line by line code as i'm new to php and htaccess, once again thank you.

Comment: As mentioned, you need to include your current `.htaccess` file in your question. What you are describing sounds like a conflict with existing directives. (?)